# Remove all <br/> tags from CKEditor Output html

Tags: regex, html-parsing, ckeditor

I am using CKeditor in my application.When i save content of the CKEditor output is added with 
 tags like this.

```
<B>Summary:</B> 
<P><BR><SPAN style="TEXT-ALIGN: left; WIDOWS: 2; TEXT-TRANSFORM: none; BACKGROUND-COLOR: rgb(255,255,255); TEXT-INDENT: 0px; LETTER-SPACING: normal; DISPLAY: inline !important; FONT: 15px/20px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; WHITE-SPACE: normal; ORPHANS: 2; FLOAT: none; COLOR: rgb(0,0,0); WORD-SPACING: 0px; -webkit-text-size-adjust: auto; -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px">The company's latest tweet simply states that "our team continues to investigate, but at this time, we're still unable to confirm that any security breach has occurred. Stay tuned here."</SPAN></P><BR>
<P><BR>Facebook&nbsp; : <A href="http://www.facebook.com">http://www.facebook.com</A></P><BR>
```

How Can I remove all the "break" tags out of above sample using regular exression in javascript.

Upon Save Text should be appended to "Summary : " like here

> Summary: Call back the department if you have not heard from them.The initial story was triggered after a user in a Russian forum
>   claimed that he hacked and uploaded almost 6.5 millionThe initial
>   story was triggered after a user in a Russian forum claimed that he
>   hacked and uploaded almost 6.5 million

But now it's coming like this

> Summary:
>
> The initial story was triggered after a user in a Russian forum
>   claimed that he hacked and uploaded almost 6.5 millionThe initial
>   story was triggered after a user in a Russian forum claimed that he
>   hacked and uploaded almost 6.5 million

I am using replace(/[\n\r\f]/g, ' ') ;

replace(/\<!>[\s\S]*?\<!>/ig, '')

but no use.help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally

> `CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.getData().replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");`

worked perfectly for my issue.

Thanks.

Comment: This was a complete pain. CKeditor is so damn good, otherwise. +1 for the fix.

Answer (score 1):

```
replace(/[\n\r\f]/g, ' ') ;
```

will remove actual newlines not the coded ones
try

```
replace(/<BR>/g, '') ;
```

or if you want to remove all tags

```
replace(/<[^>]*?>/g, ' ') ;
```

Comment: I tried it but still getting the breaks when i am extracting the html out of CKeditor.